# C++ functions with pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

What is the error? How to solve it? This code is to find the area of the circle using pointers and functions. The error I am facing is that the `&answer` cannot be converted into float.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void area(float, float);

int main()
{
    float radius, answer = 0.0;
    cout << "Enter a radius:";  // Take the radius from the user.
    cin  >> radius;
    area(&radius, &answer);
    cout << "Area of circle is:" << answer;
    return 0;

}

void area(float *value, float *result)  // This is the function to calculate the area.
{
    *result = 3.142 * (*value) * (*value);
}
```

Comment: `void area(float,float);` Your prototype doesn't take pointers.

Comment: Is this `c++11` or `c++14`? It can't be both at the same time, so edit your question to include the one you're using.

Comment: @TrebledJ is correct you should change the forward decleration as it doesn't match the function.

Comment: Don't use pointers this way. The whole function should just be `float area(float value)
{
    return 3.142f * value * value;
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do one of the 2 things:

- Change the prototype to `void area(float*, float*);`
- Remove the prototype and move the function:

  ```
  void area(float *value, float *result)  // This is the function to calculate the area.
  {
      *result = 3.142 * (*value) * (*value);
  }
  ```

above the `main()` function. Either of these will work.

Comment: Thanks alot got it !!